# how can i fix this error errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, acl, laravel-6

I want to migrate a acl migration in laravel but i got this error

**ERROR**

> 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

**TABLE**

```
public function up()
    {


        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->Increments('id');
            $table->string('title_fa');
            $table->string('title_en');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->Increments('id');
            $table->string('title_fa');
            $table->string('title_en');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('role_id');
            $table->integer('user_id');

            $table->foreign('role_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('roles')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });

        Schema::create('permission_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('permission_id');
            $table->integer('role_id');

            $table->foreign('permission_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('permissions')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('role_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('roles')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

---

I try unsign inteager for role id and user `id` and I try it:

```
 $table->primary(['role_id','user_id']);
```

but it didn't for me

Answer (score 0):

You want to change your integer to unsigned biginteger like this:

```
public function up() {

    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('title_fa');
        $table->string('title_en');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('title_fa');
        $table->string('title_en');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');

        $table->foreign('role_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('roles')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });

    Schema::create('permission_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('permission_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');

        $table->foreign('permission_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('permissions')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('role_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('roles')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```